# jQuery Ajax Json Parsing in HTML File Not Working with Google Cloud Service

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been working with jQuery/JavaScript and ajax for the first time and I am trying to work with the weather underground API to display some weather information on a web-page hosted on google cloud.

I have been reading the weather underground code example and I am trying to work with that which is why the code will look so familiar but I am just trying to get it to work so I can move forward. I have also looked at other stack overflow where similar code questions were asked but I am still not getting anywhere. I apologize for the redundancy but I am unsure why it is not working.

Everything seems to be making sense but when the HTML is suppose to "alert" when the page is loaded I am getting nothing. I would really appreciate some input even if I am doing something stupid just want to get this chunk working in order to move forward.

Below is my HTML file that is a mix of JavaScript and HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Hello, The Cloud!</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello, The Cloud!</h1>
    <p> Lets Check the Weather! </p>
  </body>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/47acb7d74302f585/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
      var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
      alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
      }
      });
    });

  </script>

</html>
```

My simple CSS file is shown below.

```
h1 {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

body {
    background-color: LavenderBlush;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    color: #FF0000;
    id: "clockbox";
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;

    width: 420px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin: 0; 
}

.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336; /* Red */
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

I appreciate any feedback!

Thank you

Comment: Well, you closed the `body` before the scripts ?

Comment: Otherwise, seems fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/pw8fgfds/1/

Comment: Did you check the console? Im guessing there's a HTTPS issue, Google Cloud probably works on HTTPS, but you are requesting the Underground's API via HTTP.

Comment: Put `<script>` inside `<body>` tag

Comment: Are you opening this page from a web server ...or from local file?

Comment: If you're not running a locally and you are running off a webserver try changing property for ajax to url: "//api.wunderground.com/api/47acb7d74302f585/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json" t

Comment: I did try to put the scripts in the body tags and I am still having the issue. @adeneo thank you for sharing that example where it works, good place to test things.

Comment: I am running from a google cloud instance and I can't seem to find anything on the console relating to any trouble with the HTTP request. @yuriy636 do you know where I could look? Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some great advice from @GAEfan and yuriy636 I was able to figure out that Google Cloud does not play well with HTTP requests thus it was just a simple change from HTTP to HTTPS in the URL's as you can see in the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Hello, The Cloud!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hello, The Cloud!</h1>
    <p> Lets Check the Weather! </p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
          url : "https://api.wunderground.com/api/47acb7d74302f585/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
          success : function(parsed_json) {
            console.log(parsed_json);
            var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
            var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
            alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
          }
        });
      });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a link to more info on Google Cloud and HTTP/HTTPS: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/

Thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have `<script>` tags inside your `<body>` tag.

This is what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Hello, The Cloud!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Hello, The Cloud!</h1>
    <p> Lets Check the Weather! </p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $.ajax({
          url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/47acb7d74302f585/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
          success : function(parsed_json) {
            var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
            var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
            alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
          }
        });
      });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to format things for sure and I appreciate the submission but it doesn't solve my problem as I still get no alert when I run it live from google cloud which makes me think it is something to do with the service not from the code?

Comment: Well, it must be the problem with something else because it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Exactly, think it has to do with Google Cloud more than the actual code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you hit an error first, you won't get to the alert.  Try adding this logging, to make sure you aren't getting a key error:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax({
      url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/47acb7d74302f585/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
      dataType : "jsonp",
      success : function(parsed_json) {
      console.log(parsed_json);
      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
      var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
      alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
      }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Very interesting! So when looking at the console with F12 on Firefox, I am seeing two items. One says "Blocked loading mixed active content “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js” and the second is "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" which makes sense since the jQuery reference call is being blocked I can't use jQuery right? Any ideas of how to approach this..?

Comment: Change to `https`: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js` or flexible: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: Figured it out, I just need to use an HTTPS request for '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>' this way I can actually use jQuery and I will change the HTTP request of the weather underground API call to HTTPS as well.